# Debugging syncdb: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'none'

Tags: django

I tried to syncdb and ended up with the following error:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'none'
```

I don't really know what this is referring to. Tried to set the verbosity level to 3 but nothing new. Any ideas how to figure out what's going on?

```
$ python manage.py syncdb
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'none'
$
```

Comment: You *did* add the switch to show the traceback... *right*?

Comment: Derp... I guess that answers the question. Thanks :)

Comment: Same problem... I expected 'manage.py' suggest me to set that option instead of passing 1 hour in debug before finding this post!